# What does the keyword 'far' mean?

Tags: keyword, pascal, procedure

I am reading some Pascal code to debug an issue on a piece of hardware. I am not familiar with Pascal, but it doesn't seem too difficult to read with a little Googling.

However, I ran across this procedure definition:

```
procedure RS232ConfigTask; far;
begin
    RS232Config.Init;
    RS232Config.Process;
end;
```

What does the 'far' keyword mean?

I've tried to look it up. I found this remark on the GNU Pascal website:

> The far directive can be appended to a procedure or function heading but is ignored by GPC. It is there for Borland compatibility, only. (Since the GNU compilers provide a flat memory model, the distinction between near and far pointers is void.)

I looked up near and far pointers, and found that it had something to do with segmented memory models, and referencing memory in other segments.

Okay.

This isn't a pointer though. So why would you mark a procedure 'far'?

---

I note that the procedure is called like so:

```
procedure Init;
begin
    CreateTask(@RS232ConfigTask, 4096, 'Config 232');
    CreateTask(@RS485ConfigTask, 4096, 'Config 485');
end;
```

If that helps.

Comment: Functions are called via their address (i.e. pointers).

Comment: Okay, great. So are the procedures called within the procedure called using far pointers, does it imply something about how this procedures pointer is going to be stored?

Comment: `far` is used in older x86 architectures where you needed to tell the compiler or assembler that you wanted a *far pointer*, which explicitly includes the segment as well as the offset to represent the address.

Answer (score 2):

Used as a procedure directive, `far` means that the subroutine must be called with a far call instruction which modifies the code segment and the instruction pointer. It means also that the call instruction pushes a far pointer (4 bytes, segment and offset) onto the stack. Further, to return to the caller, the subroutine uses a far ret instruction which expects a far pointer being pushed as a return address onto the stack.

For Turbo Pascal the following rule of thumb applies: Subroutines exported from a unit use implicitly the far calling convention as decribed above. Other subroutines use the near calling conventions (only offset modified by call/ret). To override this behaviour, `near` and `far` procedure directives were introduced.

Answer (score 0):

'Far' is an old extension which it means - "this is a pointer that needs to be able to point at any address, not just things in the same segment as the code using it".

You can go and look at the wikipedia page and read about it if you want to know more information on it. [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer)

Comment: Note that the wikipedia article describes the data pointer variant. This is the code symbol variant. (I avoid pointer on purpose here because in some Pascal dialects, a function type can be multiple pointers/addresses)

Comment: I already have this information in the question. It doesn't really help. How does the far keyword apply to a procedure definition, as used in the question?